# Why cudaGLSetGLDevice failed, even though it's called in the first line of main function

Tags: opengl, interop, cuda

I want to use interoperability between OpenGL and CUDA. I know, as some tutorials said, the first step is to choose device. However, when I called the cudaGLSetGLDevice(0) in the first line of the main function, the program exited with the information "cudaSafeCall() Runtime API error 36: cannot set while device is active in this process."

Actually, even though I use cudaDeviceProp and cudaChooseDevice before calling cudaGLSetDevice, the error still exists.

Believe me, my computer just has one GPU, 9800GT. And I do know that the calling of cudaGLSetGLDevice should be prior to any other CUDA function so that's why I put it in the first line of main function.

And I use the Windows SDK to render OpenGL instead of glut, is problem about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need in opengl context initialized before call `cudaGLSetDevice`. In case of glut `glutInit(argc, argv);` is called. Initialize opengl context before use any cuda<->opengl interoperability functions call.

Comment: Thanks dude. But I use the Windows SDK like NeHe's frame instead of glut. If not get you wrong, I think the context initialization is ChoosePixelFormat SetPixelFormat wglCreateContext wglMakeCurrent. So, after these function called, I called the cudaGLSetGLDevice. However, the error still exist. would you mind help me a liitle more? Thanks.

Comment: This answer is partially right. Besides set OpenGL context, we need the glewInit() before cudaGLSetDevice.