# Error: Cannot set while device is active in this process

Tags: cuda

I am getting error from kernel: Cannot set while device is active in this process.

Can you give me advice what does it means?

Kernel is substitution for `cudaMemset()`. Kernel should be faster than `cudaMemset()`.

Kernel:

```
__global__ void kernelMemSet ( float *sSum, float *cSum, int length ){

int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

int tid = idx*length + idy;

cSum[idx] = 0.0f;
sSum[idx] = 0.0f;
}
```

Kernel is called in cycle and error occurs only in first call, when kernel is called for second time, third, ... there is no error.

Is it possible that error is caused by call to `cudaSetDevice()` before `cudaGLSetDevice()`? - found answe they are mutually exclusive, but this is not what is causing the problem.

Comment: Can you show the host side code where the kernel is called? Your problem isn't in the kernel code, it is in the host code somewhere.

Comment: Host code is long to post it here (500 lines). It is part of CUDA OpenGL program called from LabView. but array `cSum` and `sSum` do not take part in openGL, cSum and sSum just temporary store values. I am sorry for being so unspecific.

Comment: Right, so if you are using CUDA-OpenGL interoperability APIs, that is where the problem probably is. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10481499/681865) for an example. That is about as much help as you will get without a concrete example program which illustrates the problem.

Comment: after searching on net I found: "This error can also be returned if using runtime/driver interoperability and there is an existing CUcontext active on the host thread." so it is probably caused by LabVIEW. To call CUDA function from LabVIEW, CUDA context has to be created, so this probably cause error.